# How to convert file data to plain hex?

Tags: linux, command-line, hexdump, xxd

How to easily convert to/from plain machine-readable hexadecimal data (without any paddings/offsets/character view) with `xdd` or `hexdump`?

I'm tired of digging of some special format strings (and finding out that it suddenly starts wrapping lines after N characters or skip lines) or writing Perl one-liners every time.

Why is it not as simple as `base64`/`base64 -d`?

Comment: Because almost no one needs it.

Comment: `base64` *does* wrap the output by default.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%02x"'
```

```
xxd -p | tr -d '\n'
```

If you get tired of writing *this* every time, create an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command)).

Comment: I'm tired of looking at man page and gettings confused either by necessity to compose hexdump's formt strings or by xxd's "postscript" thing. (Is this "postscript" something about printers or about letters?)

Comment: @Vi, think of -p as "plain". I surmise the Postscript comment is because the Postscript language allows for in-line data (typically images) encoded exactly this way. So Postscript programmers may use xxd to convert binary images into a convenient form for embedding in a Postscript file.

Comment: For uppercase hexadecimal output with `xxd`, use `-u`.

Answer (score 11):

> **How to easily convert to/from plain machine-readable hexadecimal data**

In brief.

```
$ xxd -plain test.txt > test.hex
$ xxd -plain -revert test.hex test2.txt
$ diff test.txt test2.txt
$
```

---

Explanation:

```
$ xxd -plain test.txt > test.hex
```

This writes a hex encoding of the data in test.txt into new file test.hex.
The `-p` or `-plain` option makes xxd use "plain" hex format with no spaces between pairs of hex digits (i.e. no spaces between byte values). This converts "abc ABC" to "61626320414243". Without the `-p` it would convert the text to a 16-bit word oriented traditional hexdump format, which is arguably easier to read but less compact and therefore less suitable as a transmission format and slightly harder to reverse.

```
$ xxd -plain -revert text.hex test2.txt
```

This uses the `-r` or `-revert` option for reverse operation. 
The `-plain` option is used again to indicate that the input hex file is in plain format.

I make the output filename different from the original filename so we can later compare the results with the original file.

```
$ diff test.txt test2.txt
$
```

The diff command outputs nothing - this means there is no difference between the original and reconstituted file contents.

---

> **I'm tired of digging of some special format strings**

Use alias or declare functions in your .profile to create mnemonics so you don't have to remember or dig about in man pages.

or just remember `-plain` and `-revert`.

---

> **Wrapped output**

Yes, there are new-line characters in the output. You want to avoid that. 
You can use the `-c` or `-cols` option to specify how long you want the output lines to be to attempt to avoid line-wrapping of the output. `-c 0` gives the default length and the man page suggests 256 is the limit but it seems to work beyond that.

```
$ xxd -plain -cols 9999 test.txt > test.hex
$ wc test.txt test.hex
  121   880  4603 test.txt
    1     1  9207 test.hex
```

The `wc` wordcount command tells us how many lines, words and characters are in each file.

So 121 lines (880 words, 4603 bytes) of ASCII text were encoded as 1 line of hex digits.

Comment: (was skipping "-p" option while reading man because of mysterious "postscript" thing)

Comment: Wrapped output.

Comment: @Vi: I understand. Out of curiosity, what is the problem with wrapped output (i.e. a small percent of arguably superfluous LF chars)?

Comment: It can be a problem if including hex in config files, like INIT=01303031313102 CMD1=41414141FF000000.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what the 3 command lines are doing (by editing the answer)?

Comment: @Peter. I've done that.

Comment: There is one little thing that is not noticed. And that is the `0x0A` that suddenly appears as last byte. You have to erase that last byte by `truncate -s -1 /tmp/file.bin`

Answer (score 3):

Here is the version using `od` utility (part of `coreutils` package):

```
od -An < input | tr -dc '[:alnum:]'
```